# How to filter specific data from API and display it in React Native Flatlist?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am making a react native app to show all live and upcoming coding contests using API. The API results are like this -

```
Object {
  "duration": "1209300.0",
  "end_time": "2022-06-12T18:25:00.000Z",
  "in_24_hours": "No",
  "name": "HackForGood: Grab Hackathon 2022",
  "site": "HackerEarth",
  "start_time": "2022-05-29T18:30:00.000Z",
  "status": "CODING",
  "url": "https://grabhackforgood.hackerearth.com/",
}
Object {
  "duration": "1641540.0",
  "end_time": "2022-06-19T15:59:00.000Z",
  "in_24_hours": "No",
  "name": "Microsoft Virtual Hackathon 2022",
  "site": "HackerEarth",
  "start_time": "2022-05-31T16:00:00.000Z",
  "status": "CODING",
  "url": "https://www.hackerearth.com/challenges/hackathon/microsoft-virtual-hackathon-2022/",
}
Object {
  "duration": "7200.0",
  "end_time": "2022-06-01T13:00:00.000Z",
  "in_24_hours": "Yes",
  "name": "TCO22 Algorithm Round 2B",
  "site": "TopCoder",
  "start_time": "2022-06-01T11:00:00.000Z",
  "status": "BEFORE",
  "url": "https://www.topcoder.com/challenges",
}
Object {
  "duration": "10800",
  "end_time": "2022-06-01 17:30:00 UTC",
  "in_24_hours": "Yes",
  "name": "CodeChef Starters 41",
  "site": "CodeChef",
  "start_time": "2022-06-01 14:30:00 UTC",
  "status": "BEFORE",
  "url": "https://www.codechef.com/START41",
}
```

I want to display details about only those contests whose `status` value is "CODING", in the flatlist.

App.js (The ContestItem is just an item component showing details about each contest)

```
export default function App() {

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
    const [originalData, setOriginalData] = useState([])

    const fetchAllContests = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`https://kontests.net/api/v1/all`)
            const json = await response.json()
            setOriginalData([...originalData, ...json])
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
            setError(e)
        } finally {
            setLoading(false)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchAllContests()
    }, [])

    return (
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
                {loading ? <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={Colors.RED}/> : (
                    <FlatList
                        style={styles.flatList}
                        data={originalData}
                        keyExtractor={({id}) => keyGenerator()}
                        renderItem={({item}) => (
                            <ContestItem
                                item={item}
                            />
                        )}
                    />
                )}
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `filter` the `originalData` on `status === "CODING"`.

```
<FlatList
   style={styles.flatList}
   data={originalData.filter(contest => contest.status === "CODING")}
```

Assuming, API result is an array of objects.

Comment: Also sir, if I want to filter results with "status" as "CODING" and "site" as "HackerEarth", how can I do that?

Comment: @san `contest.status === "CODING" && contest.site === "HackerEarth"`